# Query when a range of cells on another tab match cells on the current tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets to try to create an invoice. Currently, employees fill out a google form that feeds to a Google Sheet (GS). I'm trying to create an easy way to make an invoice by selecting each client.

As you can see on [this form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-mn6Q8cf2HI9DgKax0MuFDrMfWQScwQhlG09815ek-k/edit?usp=sharing), I have a ref tab set up so I can enter in billing addresses and such. My second tab in the GS is the invoice. And my third tab is the responses I get from the form.

I have the first part done on the Invoice form where I can select the Client Name and the billing information comes up. But I can't get the meat of the invoice to work. I want to only pull up certain columns off of the Form Response Tab if they match the client name. The closest I've gotten it to work is =QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:K, "A, B, C, D, E, F where 'Form Responses 1'!A2:A  ' "& C5 &"' )")

Can anyone help?

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:K, "Select B, C, D, E, F, G where A ='"& C5 &"'",0)
```

Also see the highlighted cell in the INVOICES tab.

Comment: Thank you JPV. I did link the sheet so you could take a look. I believe there are edit rights to it.

Comment: Another question, say I want to actually have it look up 2 criteria. Where A = '"& c5 &"' and H = "..Processed - Bill". Could that be written into the formula?

Comment: Use single quotes around '..Processed - Bill' . "Select B, C, D, E, F, G where A = ' "& C5 &" ' and H = '..Processed - Bill' "